# Git blame a list of authors in a file

Tags: git, bash

Is there a way to find out a list of authors who edited the class in java file in repo using `git blame`? The list of authors have to be unique.

I have tried using the following command but it did not remove duplicates and there is word "author" in every line of output. There is no need to sort the output, but I hope to get output without any duplicates.

```
git blame filename --porcelain | grep  "^author "
```

Expected output should be just author name: `John Michael`

Comment: If you're interested in the committers who changed a given path, not *what* they changed in the path, `git shortlog -sn -- <path>` will get you a long way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add at the end of the command `uniq` to make author unique.

```
git blame filename --porcelain | grep  "^author " | sort -u
```

[sort Documentation](http://www.linux-france.org/article/man-fr/man1/sort-1.html)

Comment: Or instead of `| sort | uniq`, just `| sort -u`.

Comment: Count each line changed by author, sort by coun desc:
`git blame filename --line-porcelain | grep  "^author " | sort | uniq -c | sort -r`