# Restrict Github collaborators to only modifying their own files on a repo?

Tags: github, github-actions, access-control, repo, collaboration

this might not sound too practical

but i want github collaborators to only be able to modify / make changes to the files that **they themselves** uploaded on the repository

they should not be able to replace, rename, edit or modify files uploaded by other collaborators in the same repository

is this possible to achieve in a private repository on github ?

If so, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Git operates at a repository level, so if a collaborator can push to a repository, they can clone, modify locally any file and push back.

You can isolate their work through fork and pull request.
And use an GitHub action like [`check-new-commits`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-new-commits) (modify for your purpose) to check if each commits only includes files [whose list of authors is limited to one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549242/6309).